# How to set label color and alignment for uibutton dynamically

Tags: ios, dynamic, colors, uibutton

I am using the following code to set the title label's text color, alignment and font size when adding a ui button in xcode. The font size is picked up but not the text color and alignment, why? Thanks.

```
toButton.titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
toButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
toButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:FONT_SIZE];
[toButton setTitle:fromButton.titleLabel.text forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Try to use setters instead of properties. [toButton.titleLabel setTextColor: [UIColor redColor]]

Comment: @ValeryPavlov Setters and properties execute the same code at runtime, there is no difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are setting the color to `titleLabel` instead of this, use:

```
[toButton setTitleColor:[UIColor redColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

For text alignment this line will work:

```
toButton.titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentRight;
```

You can also use:

```
toButton.contentHorizontalAlignment = UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentRight;
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the title color. What about the alignment, are there methods to set the alignment of a button label?

Comment: setting toButton.titleLabel.textAlignment does not work. Will try the contentHorizontalAlignment.